# Niginx Downloads PHP files Instead of Executing index.php

Tags: php, nginx

Nginx downloads php file instead executing

Ubuntu 16.04 Nginx with PHP 7.0.

nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

The files I have to execute are located in `/var/lib/customdir/customfiles/index.php`

This is my default conf file. I have removed the actual names of the directories for security reasons.

```
 # Default server configuration
 #
 server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782


         root /var/lib/customdir/customfiles/index.php

    # root /var/www/html;

    # root /usr/share/nginx/html;


    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 54.252.213.xxx;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

  location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
```

I have tried many different variations of the above without success.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
root /var/lib/customdir/customfiles/
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

here I've updated `root` (to point to root not to file) and updated `fastcgi_pass` (to point to absolute dir `/var` not to relative one).

Answer (score 0):

1) The root should be `root /var/lib/customdir/customfiles` (without file index.php).

2) Check `cgi.fix_pathinfo` value in `/etc/php7.0/fpm/php.ini` (or `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`)?  It needs to be set to `0`.

3) Modify your `location ~ \.php$` directive as:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; #you have a missing / before var
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; #add this line
}
```

Test the configuration with:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

to see if there is any error before you reload the nginx configuration.